# Does the request method affect the number of buffered items?

Tags: rx-java

I tried below in RxJva 2.0.0-RC3.

```
Flowable.interval(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .doOnNext(System.out::println)
    .observeOn(Schedulers.computation(), false, 10)
    .subscribe(new ResourceSubscriber<Long>() {

      @Override
      protected void onStart() {
        request(1);
      }

      @Override
      public void onNext(Long t) {
        try {
          Thread.sleep(30);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("received: " + t);
        request(1L);
      }
      ...
    });
```

Then, I got the below result.

```
0
1
2
3
received: 0
4
5
6
received: 1
7
8
9
received: 2
received: 3
io.reactivex.exceptions.MissingBackpressureException: Can't deliver value 10 due to lack of requests
...
```

I expected to get a MissingBackpressureException after a flowable would emit around 13 because 0, 1, 2 and 3 were already emitted, so the number of buffered items might be 6 when a flowable emitted 10. It seems that the request method would not affect the number of buffered items.

I tried the similar code in RxJava 1.2.0 and I got the different result.

```
...
20
21
received: 6
22
23
24
received: 7
25
rx.exceptions.MissingBackpressureException
...
```

Version 1.2.0's result is also confusing since the number of buffered items might be 18 (8 through 25) when the exception were thrown and the number of buffered items would be more than 10.

Are those the appropriate behavior?
I thought that a MissingBackpressureException would be thrown when the number of buffered items became more than the buffer size.

The reason why I want a MissingBackpressureException is that I want to stop the flowable or observable as soon as the number of waiting items reached more than the buffer size.

So, I can quickly ask the users to wait a while when the system were to busy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 1.x, `interval` ignores backpressure. In both versions, a prefetch of 10 will create a 16 element internal buffer in `observeOn` but 1.x `interval` will happily overflow this buffer. In addition, `observeOn` requests more from its source after 75% of the prefetch amount has been delivered (~7). In 1.x, this doesn't matter and as both ends move, you get the MBE after around 24 elements. In 2.x, the initial request of 10 is being delivered but since only 3 ever gets consumed in that time, `observeOn` doesn't re-request and you get an immediate MBE.

Comment: Thank you for the information! Now, I understand the mechanism. However,  I wonder why the cache mechanism would be like this. Is this for the performance reason?